# Quotes for String and Cell Reference

Tags: vba, string, quotes

I need to convert an excel formula into VBA codes, however I tried many times but no luck.
Below is the formula which I need to convert.

```
=IF(G7959<0, "Delivered to end customer " & E7959, "To be delivered to end customer " & E7959)
```

Below is what I have tried but did not success,the parameter 'IC_inventory_new_row' represent a variable row index. Could anyone help to take a look and advise?

```
IC_inventory_WS.Cells(IC_inventory_new_row, 15).Formula = "=IF(G" & IC_inventory_new_row + 1 & "<0, " & "Delivered to end customer" & "E" & IC_inventory_new_row & "," & "To be delivered to end customer " & "E" & IC_inventory_new_row & ")"
```

Comment: Best is to use `Debug.Print` and check the concatenation of the formula. You'll start noticing that to implement string values you'd need to double/triple up the quotes. Btw, you don't need to seperate a comma from the rest of the string to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, please:

```
IC_inventory_WS.Cells(IC_inventory_new_row, 15).formula = "=IF(G" & IC_inventory_new_row + 1 & _
            "<0, ""Delivered to end customer ""&E" & IC_inventory_new_row & _
            ", ""To be delivered to end customer ""&E" & IC_inventory_new_row & ")"
```

But it can be written in a way to not needing iteration. I mean, to drop it in all the range at once. Try this way which should do what you need, if i correctly understood what is needed:

```
IC_inventory_WS.Range("O2:O" & lastRow).formula = "=IF(" & Range("G2").address(0, 0) & _
            "<0, ""Delivered to end customer ""&" & Range("E2").address(0, 0) & _
            ", ""To be delivered to end customer ""&" & Range("E2").address(0, 0) & ")"
```

If not, please specify what does it against what you really need.

Comment: Thanks Fane, yours answer did the trick! however, could you please also help to convert below formula into VBA?    =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("To be delivered",O7962)),"","Completed")

Comment: I am driving now. I will try helping when  I will be home.

Comment: Thanks, also in this case, 'IC_inventory_new_row' represent a variable row index

Comment: @Nicholas Kan: I am not sure I understand what you mean saying something about IC_inventory_new_row, which does not appear in the formula... Do you mean replacing of 7962 from "O7962" with `"O" & C_inventory_new_row`? If yes, the formula should be: `"=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""To be delivered"",O" & C_inventory_new_row & ")),"""",""Completed"")"`